# Firefox 55.0.3 (64-bit) - javascript element.dispatchEvent() not firing unless in debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

In Firefox 55.0.3 (64-bit), the following javascript (forming part of an object function):

```
 console.log(vField.getAttribute('oninput'));
 var vEvent = new Event("input");
 var vCancelled = ! vField.dispatchEvent(vEvent);
 if (!vCancelled) {
   console.log(vEvent);
 }
```

outputs the following to the Firefox Console as expected:

> H.eventFn(this,3,'smbtn');
>
> input { target: <input#mnPWS.string.newP.x01>, isTrusted: false, eventPhase: 0, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false, composed: false, timeStamp: 7655.60940690126, cancelBubble: false, originalTarget: <input#mnPWS.string.newP.x01>, explicitOriginalTarget: <input#mnPWS.string.newP.x01> }

**The problem:** dispatchEvent() doesn't execute the H.eventFn() function. ...unless I insert a debugger breakpoint either on or before the statement:

```
var vCancelled = ! vField.dispatchEvent(vEvent);
```

The behaviour I'm seeing is:

> 1. with a debugger breakpoint as above - executes H.eventFn() fine.
> 2. with a debugger breakpoint anywhere after the above line - doesn't execute H.eventFn().
> 3. with no breakpoint at all - doesn't execute H.eventFn().

(As a side note - Chrome executes H.eventFn() fine using the same code, and neither browser shows any javascript errors I can see)

I am completely baffled by this behaviour, and would be grateful for any input anyone may have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

During the processing following occurs:

```
...
vField.disabled = true;
...
[XHR request and response]
...
vField.disabled = false;

[followed by the statements in my question above]
```

I have identified that commenting out the line disabling the field as follows:

```
// vField.disabled = true;
```

results in the code working without any requirement for a breakpoint.

I can only assume that:

> - Disabling the field causes Firefox to ignore the dispatchEvent(), even though it has again been enabled by the time the dispatchEvent()
>     statement executes.
> - **unless** a breakpoint exists post the re-enable and prior to the dispatchEvent() statement, which somehow "wakes it up" again.

**Notes**

- Using the Firefox Shift-F4 JS scratchpad to disable,re-enable then dispatchEvent() (this excludes the XHR request / response). I am sadly unable to ascertain whether this is because the scratchpad provides the same "wake up" as the debugger, or whether the issue is caused by the XHR.

If anyone has any bright ideas that offer more insight than my babbling, please do shout.

NOTE: please see Kaiido's comment below for a very effective workaround for the issue.

Comment: You could try to force a reflow (simply calling `vField.offsetWidth` after modifying `disabled` should do), but that still sounds like a bug. But for what it's worth, I can't repro on 54 55 56 on osX

Comment: @Kaiido - you are an extraordinarily clever person. thank you so much! (I agree it appears to be a bug)